# installing nodejs without dependencies

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation, npm

Hi i am having a ubuntu server which will not have any internet connection. I need to install node and all npm related packages to it.I have the source file of nodejs and all the node modules. Is there any way to install the build essential package and the python dependencies without using the below code

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
sudo apt-get install python libssl-dev -y
```

These commands actually hit a external url which will be impossible since there is no internet connection.I am stuck here.Any help will be much helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
$tar -zxf node-v0.10.5.tar.gz 
$cd node-v0.10.5
$./configure && make && sudo make install
```

just download node first from http://nodejs.org/download/

each npm package can stand alone, so by using npm on a machine that has a connection, you can then move the node_modules file with your modules to the new machine.

Comment: If i have to install any module globally say npm install forever -g will that work if i just move the folders

Comment: I tried the above procedure.Below is the error that i got    make[1]: g++: Command not found
make[1]: *** [/home/user1/Desktop/node-v0.8.12/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/accessors.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user1/Desktop/node-v0.8.12/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2

Comment: EDIT: g++ is not installed, ill look for a way to add that.

Try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1513430

Comment: and on your second question, I do not know if globals work the same way, I always use local

Comment: what if i compile node in one machine and move just the compiled  source  into the other machine will that work

Comment: I'm not sure that would work, as I think g++ is still required.